# Over-quote problem with ruby, activerecord and composite_primary_keys on oracle

Tags: ruby, activerecord, composite-primary-key

I am getting an Oracle error because of the SQL being generated for an association between tables.  There is no compound primary key involved, but this problem did not occur before adding the composite_primary_keys gem.

The association's foreign key is being added to the SQL like so:

```
SELECT "FOO".* FROM "FOO"  WHERE "FOO"."Bar_id" = 1234
```

The column "bar_id" does exist.  However, when we put "Bar_id" in quotes this way, Oracle takes us seriously, and goes all case sensitive.

If only we were generating this:

```
SELECT "FOO".* FROM "FOO"  WHERE "FOO".Bar_id = 1234
```

or this:

```
SELECT "FOO".* FROM "FOO"  WHERE "FOO"."BAR_ID" = 1234
```

We'd be fine.

Here's the error we're getting:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: NativeException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "FOO"."Bar_id": invalid identifier
```

I actually fixed (read, "hacked") this for version 3.1.0 of the composite_primary_keys gem, but now that I need to upgrade to 4.0.0, the code changes have been so significant that the simple hacks I used before are no longer so obvious.

Any idea how to fix this?

Versions of Stuff Used:

- composite_primary_keys 4.0.0
- activerecord 3.1.0
- activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter 1.4.0
- jruby 1.6.3

Comment: Note: what I said about composite_primary_keys bringing in this problem was true for version 3.1.0 of that gem.  However, now that I'm on 3.1.0 of _activerecord_, I removed composite_primary_keys and tested it (on some models without composite primary keys) and found that I still get the same problem without the composite_primary_keys gem required.  So I conclude the problem is likely coming from activerecord 3.1.0 (not composite_primary_keys 4.0.0)?

Comment: "Bar_id" is coming from an explicitly specified :foreign_key in the "Foo" model.  I'm specifying the foreign key because actually, in my case, it's more like "bar_seq_id".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I *think* I found the problem.  (Hat tip to mu_is_too_short for putting me on the right track.)

```
While foot.uninjured? { pull_trigger }...
```

Because our tables don't follow ActiveRecord convention for primary and foreign keys, but end with "_seq_id" instead of just "_id", we wrote an override for ActiveSupport::Inflector.foreign_key which basically demodulizes the model's class name and tacks "_seq_id" on the end.  The demodulize method is the one that leaves us with "Bar" which then becomes "Bar_seq_id".

So, by upcasing the whole inflected foreign key, we can make this problem go away.  Totally weird.